# Does LocalStorage support Custom (i.e. non-primitive type) Object Storage and Retrieval in any way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, local-storage

So I would like to pass an object "Hello" in JavaScript file hello.js to another JavaScript file chat.js.

Hello contains members such as Strophe.Connections, and others.

I read that I could use LocalStorage, i.e. LocalStorage.SetItem("Hello", Hello) and then retrieve the object using LocalStorage.getItem("Hello").

This did not work for me, so I searched a bit more and found JSON stringify, e.g. someone at [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) and also at [How to send javascript object from one page to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474044/how-to-send-javascript-object-from-one-page-to-another-page) suggested the use of stringify.

So I tried this as well, and here is the relevant code of Hello.js:

```
var Hello = {
connection: null,
start_time: null,
log: function (msg) {
    $('#log').append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
},

send_ping: function (to) {
    var ping = $iq({
        to: to,
        type: "get",
        id: "ping1"}).c("ping", {xmlns: "urn:xmpp:ping"});

    Hello.log("Sending ping to " + to + ".");
    console.log("Sending ping to " + to + ".");

    Hello.start_time = (new Date()).getTime();
    Hello.connection.send(ping);
},

handle_pong: function (iq) {
    var elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - Hello.start_time;
    Hello.log("Received pong from server in " + elapsed + "ms.");
    console.log('Received pong from server in " + elapsed + "ms.');     
    localStorage.setItem("hello", JSON.stringify(Hello));
    return false;
    }
};
```

Here is chat.js

```
var Hello = {
conn: null
};

$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    Hello = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hello"));
    $('#input3').bind('click', 
    Hello.connection.send("someStanza"))});
```

On line Hello = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("hello")); I try to restore the object.

And 2 line beow I call Hello.connection.send. However, here it becomes clear that I was not able to pass and restore the Hello object correctly. In Google Chrome JavaScript debugger, for example, I get an error at that line stating `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"`, which I would say means basically that the Chrome JS engine was not able to find any connection.send member in the Hello Object.

This leaves two options. Either what I am trying to do (passing an object that is not a primitive data type) is not possible in the way I am doing it. Or, that it is possible in the way I am doing it, and there is simply some other error/problem I am not seeing.

If it is possible, what am I doing wrong?

If it isn't possible to pass a non-primitive data type in this way, how else can I do it?

Hope I made myself clear enough for understanding,

Thanks, br,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to `toString` the function and then store it in localStorage. Then, when you retrieve the object from localStorage, you `eval` the function. Here's a quick demo that demonstrates (it's very stupid and can be optimized/enhanced based on your needs...):

http://jsfiddle.net/nmef7utv/

```
function pack(obj){
    var packedObj = {};
    for (key in obj) {

        // If obj property is a function, toString() it.
        if (obj[key] && obj[key].constructor === Function) {
            packedObj[key] = obj[key].toString();
        } else {
            packedObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(packedObj);
}

function unpack(obj) {
    // Temporary variable to hold eval'd func, if needed
    var temp;

    // Parse obj to loop
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    for (key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "string") {
            eval('temp =' + obj[key]);

            // Assign eval'd function
            obj[key] = temp;
        } else {
            obj[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

In the fiddle, I have:

```
// Packed Item
localStorage.setItem('test', pack(Hello));

// Unpack
testObj = unpack(localStorage.getItem('test'));
testObj.handle_pong();
```

Hope this is of help!

Comment: Great idea, but "eval('temp =' + obj[key]);" seems to cause code injection. I really don't think it's a good idea to pass class definition. Only plain data should be passed in my opinion.

Comment: I definitely hear that, @wander. I do think it depends on the situation, though. In the past, I would rarely, if ever, consider the use of `eval` (other than maybe evaling an ajax response) - But then I read of a couple examples where Bing and Google were using localStorage (w/eval) to cache everything from JavaScript, to CSS, and even HTML (and images). Really cool stuff, that's otherwise not possible w/o eval. While there's definitely a chance of code injection, being smart about eval (or, more importantly, not mis-using eval) I'd say is more important. However, this is also my opinion :)

Comment: I am fairly new to all this, so not sure what exactly is going on. Just read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp to get an explanation of what eval does. So to get your code to work for me, I created a third file pack.js, put the two functions you gave me (pack and unpack) in there, and included pack.js in the two html files that use hello.js and chat.js. Then I pack the object as you did above, in hello.js, and try to unpack it in chat.js. However I still get the same error when trying to execute Hello.connection.send(). Am I missing something/do I need to make changes to your code?

Comment: Actually, another thing that is happening is also that once I unpack the object, my browser starts flickering and behaving weird. I am guessing this may be the mentioned code injection?

Comment: @wander: Following your opinion that objects such as the one I am trying to pass would better not be passed like this, would you suggest another solution for this issue?

Comment: Hey @user2606742, the `eval` call should not cause flickering. Code injection is usually a term referred to when a third party (and typically malicious member) adds (or injects) script to your page. For instance, imagine your chat room "packed" all messages (I know, it's a crazy idea...) and a malicious user of your chatroom realized that. They could send a message like: "(function(){alert('Hello guys. It was nice seeing you!');location.href='//mysite.com'}())" and when that (otherwise normal message) got eval'd, the users would see the alert and then the redirection.

Comment: As for why it's not working -- One thing I should mention is that `pack` is really, REALLY dumb. It assumes a flat object, so something like `Hello.connection = function(){}` would work, but `Hello.connection.send = function(){}` would not (because of the nested nature of `send`...so it would never be `toString()`ed) For that, you would need to update the `pack` method and add some recursion to pack the child properties as well. Hope that helps! If you have trouble doing that, I'll be happy to assist.

Comment: ah, so something similar to SQL injection. Got it. As to getting pack to work, for me, I will have a look at it when I get home, although I may just try and change my architecture so that I don`t need to pass the object to another file, maybe by putting all the code in one file. Will see hen I get home. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Yep, exactly! And sounds good! I think a single file is good (performance impact) and again, if you need help with the recursion logic, let me know! Good luck!

Comment: Jack Pattishall Jr. is really nice:) In your html code,you can do this, <script type="text/javascript" src="Hello.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>(order is important). Then in chat.js you can directly use the global object 'Hello' defined in Hello.js

Comment: ah beautiful, Im gonna give that a try now! Thanks to both of you for your help :)

Comment: So your saying if I do it the way you are suggesting, then I can access THAT instance of Hello in chat.js? This isn't working for me at the moment, will post code if it can help. Basically, I have two html files associated with helo.js and chat.js. The first one, login.html, holds a form into which login data are entered, and then, via hello.js, the connection established and Hello.connection then holds this connection. Then I change window.location to chat.html. I have included hello.js and chat.js in that order in chat.html, but it seems, (continued in next comment)

Comment: when I then in chat.js access Hello, it is a new (empty) instance. Basically, I want the Hello instance created in login.html/hello.js to persist when I load chat.html/chat.js

Comment: additional note: I was thinking yesterday of putting all the logic in one js file, and maybe that way I could tackle this issue, but if possible, I would like to have it in two js files

Comment: @user2606742 Unfortunately, once your browser refreshes, you lose state. You would need a way to persist that state between the two (either via localStorage or a cookie, as you're attempting). You could pass that data back from the server side (if you need the page navigation). Another way is to use AJAX and remove the refresh/navigation all together. OR, an iframe with your login page on chat.html (same domain, so cross communication is possible) and communicate between the login page and your parent window (basically a clunkier, ajax-like solution, which isn't ajax...)

Comment: I think my next attempt will be to basically have the chat and the login both in one html page, basically as you are suggesting, and once login is done, set the login form invisible using jquery and chat window visible doing the same. However, I would still be interested in what it would mean to remove Ajax. Would you have an example of something similar somewhere, where Ajax is used and eliminates the need for page refresh/navigation?

Comment: I cant edit above comment: What I meant to say was "What it would mean to USE Ajax" (not "remove")

Comment: @user2606742 I actually have a quick question? When the user logs in, what info do you require for your function? I'm assuming that for users A and B, both will have unique properties (user ID), but the methods of `Hello` will be the same (`Hello.connection.send`)? Is is possible to do something like this: User A logs in (login.html), you store the unique data of User A in a cookie/localStorage. On chat.html, you then retrieve that unique data, and use it within your methods? Rather than store the entire object, you store just the variables required in the object.